# Encapsulate text of element instead of entire element

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list with links, except for the current pager item (li.pager-current). I would like to encapsulate it with a link also.

## Source html:

```
<ul class="pager">
    <li class="pager-first first"><a href="...">« eerste</a></li>
    <li class="pager-previous"><a href="...">‹ vorige</a></li>
    <li class="pager-item"><a href="...">1</a></li>
    <li class="pager-current">2</li>
    <li class="pager-item"><a href="...">3</a></li>
    <li class="pager-next"><a href="...">volgende ›</a></li>
    <li class="pager-last last"><a href="...">laatste »</a></li>
</ul>
```

### Current code I have is:

```
$('ul.pager li.pager-current').wrapAll(<a />);
```

#### Which makes it into:

```
    <a><li class="pager-current">2</li></a>
```

#### But wanted result is:

```
    <li class="pager-current"><a>2</a></li>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.pager-current').wrapInner('<a href="#"></a>');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/j3Xrr/).

Or, alternatively, using `html()`:

```
$('.pager-current').html(function(i,h){
    return '<a href="#">' + h + '</a>';
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/j3Xrr/1/).

References:

- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
- [`wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/).

Comment: .wrapInner()... ofcourse. I'm an idiot for not thinking something like that existed.